# How to add a result to a label on TKinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label, ttk

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        ozoneStandard = 8.0
        sulphDioxStandard = 20
        particleStandard = 25
        reading1 = float(ozone_box.get())
        reading2 = float(sulphDiox_box.get())
        reading3 = float(particle_box.get())
        AQIozone = 100 * reading1 / ozoneStandard
        AQIsulphDiox = 100 * reading2 / sulphDioxStandard
        AQIparticle = 100 * reading3 / particleStandard        
        AQI.set(max(AQIozone, AQIsulphDiox, AQIparticle))
    except ValueError:
        pass

#[...etc...]

AQI = StringVar()

#[...etc...]

calculate_button = ttk.Button(frame, text='Calculate AQI', command=calculate)
calculate_button.grid(column=2, row=4, sticky=(W, E))

AQI_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable=AQI)
AQI_label.grid(column=2, row=5, sticky=(W, E))

#[...etc...]

root.mainloop()
```

I need to have a label with "AQI:" and then the result from `calculate()` following it – to two decimal places – all in the same column (and row). I'm only really used to `print()`, so what I've tried has only been printing to the console, hehe. Any and all help much appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with: `AQI.set(max(AQIozone, AQIsulphDiox, AQIparticle))`?

Comment: It only shows the result; there's no "AQI:" before it.

Comment: Replace with: `.set(f"AQI: {max(...}")`, assuming AQI is of type `StringVar`

Comment: Legend! Thanks, stovfl!
Now to try and work out the to-two-decimal-places issue...

Comment: Read up on [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: `AQI.set("AQI: {:0.2f}".format(max(AQIozone, AQIsulphDiox, AQIparticle)))` seems to work!

Comment: Oh, the AQI result label won't centre... I wonder why not... Lots of learning, I guess.

Comment: Got rid of the sticky. All solved. Thanks, again!